# Ruby unless && statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following in my application_controller.rb

```
def layout
  unless request.subdomain.empty? && current_user.nil?
    self.class.layout 'admin'
  end
end
```

It seems the code above it's not working. But when I do the following, it does work.

```
def layout
  unless request.subdomain.empty?
    unless current_user.nil?
      self.class.layout 'admin'
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to simplify the code by removing one unless statement. How could I do that?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`unless something` is equivalent to `if !something`. In your case, that would be

```
if !(request.subdomain.empty? && current_user.nil?)
```

However, you want

```
if (!request.subdomain.empty? && !current_user.nil?)
```

Using boolean algebra (De Morgan rule), you can rewrite that to

```
if !(request.subdomain.empty? || current_user.nil?)
```

Using `unless`

```
unless request.subdomain.empty? || current_user.nil?
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to set the layout to `'admin'` **if** the subdomain is **not** empty **and** the current user is **not** nil:

```
def layout
  if !request.subdomain.empty? && !current_user.nil?
    self.class.layout 'admin'
  end
end
```

Change your logic to use `if` statements and positive predicates, it will make the logic in your code much easier to understand:

```
def layout
  if request.subdomain.present? && current_user
    self.class.layout "admin"
  end
end
```

Best practice is to avoid `unless` except in the most trivial cases.

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
if (!request.subdomain.empty? && !current_user.nil?)
```

I never use `unless` with anything that is more complex (contains or/and), it's just too hard to reason about a statement like that.

Comment: Noted as thumb-rule:
Never use "unless" with anything so complex